# Can't convert Pytorch to ONNX

Tags: python, pytorch, onnx

Trying to convert [this](https://github.com/zllrunning/face-parsing.PyTorch) pytorch model with ONNX gives me this error. I've searched github and this error came up before in version 1.1.0 but was apparently rectified. Now I'm on torch 1.4.0. (python 3.6.9) and I see this error.

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/onnx/init.py", line 148, in export
strip_doc_string, dynamic_axes, keep_initializers_as_inputs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/onnx/utils.py", line 66, in export
dynamic_axes=dynamic_axes, keep_initializers_as_inputs=keep_initializers_as_inputs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/onnx/utils.py", line 416, in _export
fixed_batch_size=fixed_batch_size)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/onnx/utils.py", line 296, in _model_to_graph
fixed_batch_size=fixed_batch_size, params_dict=params_dict)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/onnx/utils.py", line 135, in _optimize_graph
graph = torch._C._jit_pass_onnx(graph, operator_export_type)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/onnx/init.py", line 179, in _run_symbolic_function
return utils._run_symbolic_function(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/onnx/utils.py", line 657, in _run_symbolic_function
return op_fn(g, *inputs, **attrs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/onnx/symbolic_helper.py", line 128, in wrapper
args = [_parse_arg(arg, arg_desc) for arg, arg_desc in zip(args, arg_descriptors)]
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/onnx/symbolic_helper.py", line 128, in
args = [_parse_arg(arg, arg_desc) for arg, arg_desc in zip(args, arg_descriptors)]
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/onnx/symbolic_helper.py", line 81, in _parse_arg
"', since it's not constant, please try to make "
RuntimeError: Failed to export an ONNX attribute 'onnx::Gather', since it's not constant, please try to make things (e.g., kernel size) static if possible
```

How to fix it? I've also tried latest nightly build, same error comes up.

My code:

```
from model import BiSeNet
import torch.onnx
import torch

net = BiSeNet(19)
net.cuda()
net.load_state_dict(torch.load('/content/drive/My Drive/Collab/fp/res/cp/79999_iter.pth'))
net.eval()

dummy = torch.rand(1,3,512,512).cuda()
torch.onnx.export(net, dummy, "Model.onnx", input_names=["image"], output_names=["output"])
```

I added `print (v.node ())` to symbolic_helper.py just before the runtime error is raised to see what's causing the error.

This is the output: `%595 : Long() = onnx::Gather[axis=0](%592, %594) # /content/drive/My Drive/Collab/fp/model.py:111:0`

And that line in 111 in model.py is: `avg = F.avg_pool2d(feat32, feat32.size()[2:])`

This [source](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.msdn.hk%2Fwzfwq%2F60524.html) suggests that tensor.size method in pytorch cannot be recognized by onnx and needs to be modified into a constant.

Answer (score 8):

I used to have a similar error when exporting using

`torch.onnx.export(model, x, ONNX_FILE_PATH)`

and I fixed it by specifying the `opset_version` like so:

`torch.onnx.export(model, x, ONNX_FILE_PATH, opset_version = 11)`

Comment: Any justification or simply trial and error?

Comment: @bob if I remember correctly, it was one of the suggestions on the Github issues. Maybe this one: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/36997#issuecomment-636321420

Comment: My case is different, but thank you anyway

Answer (score 3):

For those hitting this question from a Google search and who are getting a `Unable to cast from non-held to held instance (T& to Holder) (compile in debug mode for type information)`, try adding `operator_export_type=torch.onnx.OperatorExportTypes.ONNX_ATEN_FALLBACK` ([as mentioned here](https://github.com/pytorch/fairseq/issues/283#issuecomment-444981538)) like this:

```
torch.onnx.export(model, input, "output-name.onnx", export_params=True, opset_version=12, operator_export_type=torch.onnx.OperatorExportTypes.ONNX_ATEN_FALLBACK)
```

That fixed the "held instance" problem in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Change instances of

```
x = F.avg_pool2d(x, x.shape[2:])
```

to

```
x_shape = [int(s) for s in x.shape[2:]]
x = F.avg_pool2d(x, x_shape)
```

such that the input shape to `avg_pool2d` is constant `[k,k]`, not `torch.Size([k, k])` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/34743).

Answer (score 0):

You can:

```
print(feat32.size()[2:])
```

and replace:

```
F.avg_pool2d(feat32, feat32.size()[2:])
```

with:

```
F.avg_pool2d(feat32, your_print_contant_result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled with same issue.

F.adaptive_avg_pool2d is not supported in my case. you have to try other operations.

I hope this helps.

Thanks